# Scripting Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I'm wondering if it's possible to script certain actions of Eclipse itself. I'd like to be able to start a server, stop it, etc. Is this possible and if so, how?

Edit: I'd like to be able to do this so I can run certain server commands just through an SSH connection, no physical interaction required. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Note that [Martin OBERHUBER](http://www.blogger.com/profile/02195662278064214049) announced [in his blog](http://tmober.blogspot.fr/2012/04/scripting-eclipse.html) (April 2012):

> I've started a new initiative to get scripting support back home to Eclipse.org and unify the fragmented landscape a bit.

- a mailing list dedicated to scripting in Eclipse: [**eclipse-scripting-dev**](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipse-scripting-dev/)
- an "[Eclipse Scripting BoF session at EclipseCon 2012](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/Scripting/bofecon12)" page lists the first initiatives.

So:

- 10 years after [bug 8519 (keystroke macros recording and playing capability)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8519),
- 9 years after [bug 37680 (Add Eclipse automation)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=37680),
- 6 years after [bug 158716 (`[`Workbench`]` Pull Scripting support into platform)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=158716),

..., that topic might finally evolve.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not supported OOTB. You can configure external tools which are basically just canned command lines that you can pass workbench variables. You can write scripts externally in Perl, Python or whatever and invoke them as external commands. The output can be captured in a console tab and you configure it to trigger a workspace rebuild and/or refresh.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want to check: http://www.viplugin.com/scripteclipse.htm

I am using it to run JavaScripts inside Eclipse to automate some tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has a headless mode, mainly tailored for headless builds, but you might be able to leverage that for your purposes.  You'll probably have to create your own application or plugin to handle what you want, assuming that the features you need aren't GUI dependent.  Search Google for "eclipse headless" to get started.

Answer (score 1):

As of June 2014, the latest official scripting initiative seems to be:

[EASE](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.ease)

The project is still under incubation.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the answer from vonC:
Eclipse scripting got really active again in the last view weeks. Currently the development takes place at github: https://github.com/adaussy/EScriptMonkey
We are striving for a dedicated project in the e4 incubator. A first prototype will be available by end of October. Interested parties may visit the "Scripting baby" session at EclipseCon Europe 2013.